# OpenMP Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, openmp

OpenMP had a significant implementation change in VS2010 that led to a MS hotfix:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2686593/en-us

tl;dr: a spin-wait causes 100% cpu usage when parallelizing rather short tasks.

Can anyone tell if this behavior is still the case in Visual Studio 2012, 2013?

Best
Wendy